# Laravel Vue - Console log Axios POST response is different from network response

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

[image]

In my backend in Laravel vue app, I am sending back the same response I sent to the server.

The two console logs aren't the same, data slightly differs.

1. `DATA GOING OUT` shows the correct data being sent out
2. `DATA COMING IN` shows the wrong data coming back

However, the network response in chrome from the POST request in `(1)` does show the correct `response` though.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel/PHP isn't formatting response correctly and Vue on the frontend needs `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)` (to be placed in the create lifecycle method)

[image]